# AND version of UNION

Tags: mysql, sql, search

With union, you can join multiple select results:

```
SELECT id FROM `articles` WHERE title LIKE $query
UNION
SELECT id FROM `articles` WHERE text LIKE $query
```

The query above is of course a dumb way to do a search. It equals this:

```
SELECT id FROM `articles` WHERE title LIKE $query OR text LIKE $query
```

However, this approach might get more sense with nested selects:

```
SELECT * FROM `articles` as art WHERE exists
             (SELECT 1 FROM `users` WHERE users.id = articles.author AND username LIKE $query)"
```

Query you've just read will return articles by user name. If many nested searches are used, using union starts making sense.

But union will return results concatenated in a OR manner. I need to get the results in the AND manner, that is only return a row, if it was returned by ALL the sub-searches.
Look at the first example. I'm looking for union query that equals this:

`SELECT id FROM articles WHERE title LIKE $query AND text LIKE $query`

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. `UNION` just returns result of two queries in one grid, the only constraint that s in place is that you need to return same amount of columns, and the columns need to be of the same type.

To make the code simpler, you may use `JOIN`s instead of subqueries:

```
SELECT * FROM `articles` AS art  
INNER JOIN `users` AS u 
   ON art.author = u.id 
WHERE u.username LIKE $query
```

Comment: Is this code also faster? Can `ON` statement have more conditions?

Comment: @TomášZato Yes, `ON` can have more conditions. This code should generally be either faster or equal to the original query - if you are having performance issues, then you should probably add some indexes to the table. It won't be trivial if doing fulltext search across the fields, but on e.g. `author` on the article the index would really be handly.